# Reading values from a linked list starting from the end instead of the beginning c++

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers

I am having a little trouble with reading a linked list from the end of the head instead of the beginning. I have an insert function that reads in the beginning set of inputted numbers, displays the numbers in a list and then sums them up. It goes in the order they typed IE 1 2 3 and then displays them in a descending fashion like this:
1
2
3

I would like to have the program start at 3 for instance and then count like this:
3
2
1

The program compiles and everything but I am not sure where I am going wrong in the 'insert_at_end' function. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class List
{
    public:
        List();
        ~List();
        int sum();
        void insert(int value); // insert at beginning of list
        void insert_at_end(int value);
        void print();
    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                Node(int value, Node *next)
                {m_value = value; m_next = next;}
                int m_value;
                Node *m_next;
        };
        Node *m_head;
};

#endif

List::List()
{
    m_head = NULL;
}

List::~List()
{
    Node *ptr = m_head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        Node *temp;

        temp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->m_next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void List::insert(int value)
{
    m_head = new Node(value, m_head);
}


void List::print()
{
    Node *ptr = m_head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->m_value << endl;
        ptr = ptr->m_next;
    }

}

int List::sum()
{
    int total = 0;
    Node *ptr = m_head;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        total = total + ptr->m_value;
        ptr = ptr->m_next;
    }
    cout << "sum = " <<total<<endl;
}

void List::insert_at_end(int value)
{
    m_head = new Node(value, m_head);
    Node *ptr = m_head;
    ptr->m_value = value;
    ptr->m_next = NULL;

    if(!value)
    {
        m_head = ptr;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *last = m_head;
        while(last->m_next)
            {
            last = last->m_next;
            last->m_next = ptr;
            }
    }

}



#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    int number;
    List list;

    while(cin>>number)
    {
        list.insert_at_end(number);
        //list.insert(number);
    }

    list.print();
    list.sum();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a doubly linked list would simplify matters, as would using a [sentry node](http://pastebin.com/egDECvDi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void List::insert_at_end(int value)
{
    Node *ptr = new Node(value, NULL); // you mustn't break the m_head in this function
    // you don't have to set the value to *ptr since it is already set above

    if(!m_head) // value does no business here
    {
        m_head = ptr;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *last = m_head;
        while(last->m_next)
        {
            last = last->m_next;
        }
        last->m_next = ptr; // you mustn't break last->m_next here. get this line out of the loop
    }

}
```

Also, don't forget to return something from the `sum` function!